# Finding values of $m$ for which $\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}x=mx − 1$ has one real solution on the interval $[0,4]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> By considering possible points of intersection of the graphs of $y = 1 + \sin {\frac{\pi}{2}} x$ and $y = mx$, find
> the values of $m$ for which the equation
> $$\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}x=mx − 1$$
> has exactly one real solution in the domain
> $0 \le x \le 4$.

*Progress:*
Tried solving it graphically to no avail.

When solving it graphically I realised that for any value of $m$ there's always one solution for the sine curve for the graph in the given domain, so what's the question asking me to do, and how do I approach it?

Comment: crap forgot to add the x hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Your graphical approach was correct. If $0<m\leq 0.25$, we will have two solutions. Also for $m<0$ there are $0$ solutions in domain.

Comment: Where did you get 0.25 from? Thanks.

Comment: If you draw the graph, you will understand it clearly. The equation of line is one of variable slope, with y intercept $-1$.

Comment: So at $0.25$ slope it intersects $x$ axis at $(4,0)$

Comment: Fair enough, but is there a way to show this algebraically?

Comment: Questions like this, where you have to find number of solutions rather than exact solutions, are almost always solved graphically. Algebraic approach might or might not be possible, but the graphical approach would always be quickest.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to consider that the problem is to find the zero's of function
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2}x\right)+1}{x}-m$$ since $x=0$ is not a root.

Graphically, the problem is clear and simple.